# Create line in footer from edge of paper and three lines in header

Tags: header-footer

I have problem with creating of footer like on picture (with blue line from edge of the paper and on the left side with page number) and add three lines of text to the heard on the left side. On the right site add picture.
Any hints how code it in latex? 
thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you want this footer layout for every page? What for even and odd pages?

Comment: I need this footer same for every page thanks

Answer (score 1):

I defined a new page style with `titleps` (a companion package to `titlesec`). Is this what you want?

```
 \documentclass[oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, headheight=28pt, verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier,  erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx, stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\sethead{\sffamily\color{lightgray}{\Shortstack[l]{Text 558844454345\\ Line 2\\Line3}}}{}{{\raisebox{-4pt}[0pt]{\includegraphics[height=36pt]{pepe-le-pew1}}}}
\setfoot{\parbox{3.5cm}{\sffamily\color{lightgray}Page\, \thepage}\color{SteelBlue!60}\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{1ex}}}{}{}
}%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}


\lipsum

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry how Can I add head with three lines on the left and with logo on the right side?

Comment: It's with `\set{}{}{}`,  which is empty at the moment.  I can add it, if you explain how the three lines should be. Can you post an image (even hand drawn)  showing what you want?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @hanz: I modified my answer. Is it like you want?

Comment: almost done. But when I change the text in footer the text isnt align to left

Comment: In the footer? What do you want to put into it?

Comment: You mean in the header. I had forgotten the optional argument to `\Shortstack`. By default, it is centred. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: And how i change the font in all text to Helvetica Neue include footer and header?

Comment: Is it a text without maths?

Comment: yes, only some chapter and table of content...